# How do I change relay connection limit in graphene django

Tags: python, django, graphene-django

In graphene-django I have a pagination limit set in my `settings.py` file like below.

```py
GRAPHENE = {
    'RELAY_CONNECTION_MAX_LIMIT': 150,
}
```

Let's say a particular query returns 200 items (I don't know beforehand) and I want to display all of this data on a graph. How do I stop graphene from paginating it when returning the results?

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `max_limit` argument for every `DjangoFilterConnectionField` individually. Setting this to `None` basically disables the limiting behaviour.

Suppose you have the following query for a `UserNode` class:

```py
class UserQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_users = DjangoFilterConnectionField(UserNode, max_limit=None)
```

The `max_limit` parameter will internally be processed by the `DjangoConnectionClass` which provides the limiting behaviour via the mentioned setting `RELAY_CONNECTION_MAX_LIMIT`

Beware though that this might lead to drastic performance issues in case of very large or expensive queries. Personally I would probably go for either a *very* high but still resonable limit depending on your data or preferrably look into implementing proper pagination behaviour on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it does seem to me that the best course of action is to create a separate endpoint that doesn't go through the connection class.

Comment: Does that not kind of work around the basic idea of GraphQL? Especially in a `relay` environment where you most probably want to have a uniform api with `edges` and `nodes` etc.

Comment: It does. But I'll stick with that for now until I'm able to find what I'm looking for.