# DjangoFilterConnectionField query for all records

Tags: django, graphql, django-filter, graphene-python, graphene-django

I'm using DjangoFilterConnectionField with a django-graphene and django-filter. and I'd like to know if it's possible to get all the records via a query?

Consider the following code:

```
class Query(graphene.AbstractType):
    txt = graphene.Field(LocalizedTxtType)
    all_txts = DjangoFilterConnectionField(LocalizedLocalizedTxtType)
```

How can I get all records with no filter (i.e. allTxts) ?
Do I need to add a resolve_all myself , or does DjangoFilterConnectionField provide a way to query for all records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate of [How do I change relay connection limit in graphene django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66083573/how-do-i-change-relay-connection-limit-in-graphene-django)

By default the DjangoFilterConnectionField "max_limit" is set to 100.
If set to None, it will fetch all records:

```
all_txts = DjangoFilterConnectionField(LocalizedLocalizedTxtType, max_limit=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for getting all of the fields within a model as follows?

```
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from model.path import Model

class ModelType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = "__all__"

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    models = graphene.List(MapType)

    def resolve_models(self, info):
        return Model.objects.all()
```